# How to parse a javadoc?

Tags: java, api, parsing, documentation, javadoc

I am in the process of using Java to read javadocs.

My java object has the attributes,
Description
Package Name
 Method Name, Method Description

Is there any existing api that can do this?
How can I read the javadoc in such a way that I can extract the above mentioned attributes?

Comment: It may help to know if you are generating the Javadoc from your own code or parsing an existing closed-source API.

Comment: Do you want to parse the Javadoc comments in Java files, or the generated HTML?

Comment: do you mind sharing your solution?

Answer (score 12):

The [javadoc](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/javadoc/index.html) tool includes an API for writing custom doclets. These basically get the parsed tree of documentation fragments and they generate some kind of report based on that. The standard doclet generates the HTML pages everyone is familiar with. Your easiest option is likely to write your own doclet.