# Reading Java class documentation from code into a GUI

Tags: java, javadoc

My question today is I have a GUI that interfaces another program. I have a text area within my GUI which I would like to display the class documentation of specific components that the user selects.

Example: User selects the 'Protocol' setting I want it to show the JavaDoc for that 'Protocol'.

How do I go about recognising the correct Javadoc and presenting it within the text area?

Comment: The aim of having the class documentation available within the GUI is so as to be a useful learning aid to the users of the GUI.

Comment: Surely JavaDoc is intended to be a tool for the software developer, rather than a "Help Files for End-User" shortcut?

Comment: This tool is a protocol development utility that sits outside an API. So was just wondering if there was a way. Aside from copying all the Javadocs to internal strings then presenting them at way.

Comment: The GUI that interfaces with other program. Intends to teach the user how that 'Other program' functions at the documentation level.

Comment: If I remember correctly, the Java compiler ignores comments. So the comments are not included anywhere in the compiled classes. If you want the javadoc, you either need the source files or the exported javadoc itself. You can either fetch it from a website or from file. A good idea might be to export the javadoc using a custom doclet, that would make an output format easy to parse. Anyway, you need some link from gui components to javadoc.

Comment: Possibly related to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7657634/how-to-parse-a-javadoc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest 3 possible approaches:

- As part of your build, create Javadoc HTML as normal, and then include it in your deployable, and have your GUI use an embedded browser of some kind (eg. WebKit)
- Study how it's been done by other GUI's, such as from Eclipse's Javadoc View, or using [a project which extends Eclipse Javadoc View](http://code.google.com/a/eclipselabs.org/p/javadocasumlview/)
- Use a Java source (Javadoc) [parsing library / tool](http://qdox.codehaus.org/apidocs/com/thoughtworks/qdox/JavaDocBuilder.html), such as [QDox](http://qdox.codehaus.org/)

Example code from QDox:

```
JavaDocBuilder builder = new JavaDocBuilder();
builder.addSource(new FileReader("MyFile.java"));
```

Answer (score 2):

> ..Javadoc.. presenting it within the text area?

Don't use a `JTextArea`, but a `JEditorPane`.  The latter will render HTML.

Answer (score 1):

The JavaDoc is not part of a Java program. So you have to bundle the resources with your program regardless of what approach you use.

So you have two possibilities:

1. Generate the documentation with javadoc and bundle the result. It is easy to see how to map from a class name to the html page by looking at the generated files. The JavaDoc documentation (the Default doclet’s documentation to be more precise) contains more detailed descriptions
2. If you want to generate the documentation on-the-fly you have to bundle the source code with your application. Further, your application have to run inside a JDK rather than a plain JRE to get hands on JavaDoc.

See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/javadoc/standard-doclet.html

> Running the Standard Doclet Programmatically
>
> The Javadoc tool has a programmatic interface with public methods for
>   invoking the Javadoc tool from another program written in the Java language.
>   These methods are located in class com.sun.tools.javadoc.Main in lib/tools.jar. …
>
> public static int execute(String programName, PrintWriter errWriter, PrintWriter warnWriter,
>     PrintWriter noticeWriter, String defaultDocletClassName, String[] args)

This execute method is overloaded with variants taking fewer parameters.